# Finding if an ID exists in a table using Mysql EXISTS an PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table which keeps record of users who have given the test.Since I want the user to attempt test only once, first I check if he has given it before allowing him to take test.

`Test_Attempted`

```
-------------------------------
User_id    |  Name
-------------------------------
```

Now I am using the following query

`select exists(select user_id from Test_Attempted where user_id=45) as present`

But since id `45` is already present ,it returns

```
+---------+
| present |
+---------+
|       1 |
+---------+
```

Now I am confused how to use it in `if-else` (using PDO)

```
if(present)
   echo "You have given test";
else
   echo "Take test";
```

Do I need to cycle through rows using while loop,even if the returned row is single?

Comment: You could do 1 `fetch` instead if you know it to be 1 row, but yes, you'd normally fetch the entire resultset. I use `fetchAll()` in `PDO` though, no need for a `while` then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need a while loop if you know there's always exactly one row. It seems to me that this should be intuitively obvious, but hardly a day goes by that I don't see a question containing a while loop for a known single row.

```
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($row['present']) {
    echo "You have given test";
} else {
    echo "Take test";
}
```

Comment: :Thanks.But suppose if multiple rows would have been returned,and we used the same code you provided,then what would it have returned ?Error or data of first row?It always has confused me

Comment: Each call to `fetch` returns the next row. If you call it just once, you get the first row.

Comment: There's nothing magical about `while` loops. It just runs the same code repeatedly. Running something outside the loop just runs it once, it's just like the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: Ya I know it,but since I just migrated today to `PDO` from `mysql_` and hence some slight confusion.

Comment: It has nothing to do with mysql versus PDO. It's just basic understanding of how loops work. `while ($var = somefunc())` works the same, no matter what `somefunc` is.